# MP4 video working on desktop, not on mobile

Tags: video, mp4, ios, wordpress, h.264

I embedded a video in the following URL: https://www.speurtochten.nl/over-ons/ I made it with Premiere Pro CC, exported it as H.264.

The code I use in WordPress: `[video src="https://speurtochten.nl/sbsfilm.mp4"][/video]`

I tried uploading several dummy videos instead (http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4), and they worked perfectly fine on the desktop AND on a mobile phone.

On my iPhone, I get "Error loading this resource".

Answer (score 0):

There are several potential fixes for this kind of issue.  You do not mention the browser you are using, so please make sure you've tried on both Chrome and Safari.

- iPhones have been squirrely about playing videos, make sure you've cleaned out your browsers. And restart your iPhone.
- try a different iPhone.  Yes, these sound obvious but as a longtime iPhone-r I always try these first.

If these first ones do not work then I suggest:

- download the video to your iPhone, can you play it then?
- make sure you have very good network connectivity
- try an iPad or a PowerBook just to confirm it is not an Apple vs video issue.  (Since this is an mp4 I doubt that, but it doesn't hurt to be sure.)

If you google "iphone won't play video" you'll see a large number of posts/articles about this odd iphone & video struggle.  I doubt it is your video or your website, I'm betting on the phone first.